# Discord Bot - Move Channel Position

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm creating a bot using `Discord.js`, and I'm searching for a method to move a channel after a command.
Example:

```
!assistance -> The channels moves to a Category named "?".
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortunately, moving channels to different categories is made very easy with the [`GuildChannel.setParent()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/GuildChannel?scrollTo=setParent) method. It's fairly self-explanatory, but this function will move the specified channel to the specified category.

---

There are two things you'll need for this to work:

- The channel you want to move
- The category you want to move it to

---

Assuming the channel you want to move is the channel the message is being sent in, you can use [`message.channel`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/Message?scrollTo=channel) as the channel you want to move.

I'm also going to assume you want to *specify* which category you want to move the channel to. For example:

```
!channelMove General
```

Which would move the channel to, for example, the `General` category (if you have one). To get the channel name from that command, you could use an `args` variable.

```js
// example message
const message = '!channelMove General';

// args function will split the string by every space
const args = message.split(/ +/);

console.log(args); // this will return an array of every word

console.log(args[1]); // the second element in the array will be the category name
```

---

Using the [`GuildChannel.cache.find()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/GuildChannelManager?scrollTo=cache) method, you'll be able to find a category by its name.

```js
const givenCategory = message.client.channels.cache.find(
 (category) => category.name.toLowerCase() === args[1].toLowerCase()
);

// if that category doesn't exist, or is a channel instead of a category:
if (!givenCategory || givenCategory.type !== 'category')
 return message.channel.send('That is not a valid category name!');
```

---

Now, you can finally use the `.setParent()` method:

```js
message.channel.setParent(givenCategory);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that might help you:

```
        //Current channel ID
        const channel = message.channel;

        //The scoped category
        const scopedCategory = client.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === args[0]).id


        channel.setParent(scopedCategory)
```

First I get the channel from which the message is sent with `let channel = message.channel;`, then I get the id of the category in which I want to move my channel with `let scopedCategory = client.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === args[0]).id` (from the argument I gave in my command).
Once I have these 2 informations, I call the `.setParent` function to give it its new category.

Example:

```
!move Tst
```

[image: Test]

You can see here that my channel has been moved to the right category.

Comment: I'm newbie on discord.js, Can I have the code for study it? I'm blocked to create the command with scopedCategory (ex: "Tst") after.